# Cufon hover stays in hoverstate on mouseout

Tags: html, css, hover, cufon

http://www.basenharald.nl/3d

Hover the buttons. What i want is that the cufon text changes to #e90c00. 
For some reason (sometimes) when i move my mouse off the button it stays #e90c00.

This is the code that i use:

```
Cufon.replace('#nav li a span', {  hover: true, hoverables: { span: true}, textShadow: '#353535 1px 1px'} );
```

Does anyone know how i can fix this?

Comment: it seems you're double applying the hover effect. what happens if you remove `hoverables: { span: true}` from the options? Also, have you tried to replace `#van li a` instead?

Comment: @William Niu That won't work (tried it). It needs both hover and hoverables. Also if i set nav li a all the text becomes cufon and the hover problem still excists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue:

```
$('#nav li').hover(function(){ 
    $('a span', this).css('color','#e90c00'); 
    Cufon.refresh('#nav li a span'); 

 },function(){ // this is the mouse out 

    $('a span', this).css('color','#fff'); 
    Cufon.refresh('#nav li a span'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I came to this post looking for troubleshooting the cufon hover problem with submenu's. I was impressed with the answers and tried the reset to no avail. The following article from the cufon FAQ may help others looking for something similar:

https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/FAQ#wiki-faq-10

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/styling

some tests you can try

```
Cufon.replace('#nav li a span', {
hover: true,
hoverables: { span: true, a: true }
});


Cufon('#nav li a span', {
color: '#fff',
hover: {
    color: '#e90c00'
       }
});
```

Comment: I am sorry simon, but i already fixed that part... now the hover stays on mouse out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call Cufon.refresh(); eg:

```
$('#nav li a span').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('color','#e90c00');
    Cufon.refresh($(this));
// this is the mouse out
},function(){
    $(this).css('color','#fff');
    Cufon.refresh($(this));
});
```

Comment: it works in a way. Do i need to implement this snippet and leave the cufon.replace for the span intact? Take a look at it now if you can. It works, but it is terribly slow, way to slow.

Comment: Yes, the cufon.replace(); call comes before my snippet above. I'm surprised it's slow for you. What happens if you remove the textShadow? Is it faster?

Comment: still really really slow (i put the shadow back on since it made no difference). Isnt it so that if you use cufon.refresh it has to reload cufon every time on hover and mouseout?

Comment: Cufon.refresh(); doesn't reload Cufon, it just repeats the Cufon.replace(); calls you have. You can make it more specific by passing in a selector, see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the input sofar, but this also doesnt work. In facts i even lose the shadow now and it still is as slow as before

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your cufon code and navigation? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Is that needed? The full code is here: www.basenharald.nl/3d Isnt it better to test it there with firebug? That way we know for sure the speed is up to par in the original website.

Answer (score 0):

why not use CSS??

```
#nav li a span
{
  color: #fff;
/* and other default styles */
}
#nav li a span:hover
{
  color: #e90c00;
/* and whatever other styling u need on hover */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery script that some users have suggested is in fact the only way to get it to work properly. The Cufon styling effects that are explained in Cufon's documentation do work, but sometimes the hover effect will still display after you moved the mouse out of the button area. Which is, of course, a shame. You need at least to insert a Cufon.refresh() or Cufon.replace() after the hover is triggered. You can keep the styling with CSS, no need to implement that in the JS snippet. Here is the code I use for that case :

```
$('ul#nav ul li a').hover(function(){ 
    Cufon.refresh('ul#nav ul li a'); 
 },function(){ 
    Cufon.refresh('ul#nav ul li a'); 
});
```

With CSS, of course, something like that :

```
ul#nav li a { color: black } ul #nav li a:hover { color :red }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter snippet:

```
$('ul#nav ul li a').mouseout(function(){ Cufon.refresh('ul#nav ul li a'); });
```